# SQL nesting queries

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I wish to write two nested queries of create and select statements. My motive is to
create a new table which includes columns and entries from two other tables.
I wrote a query but it is giving me an error.

```
create table table_3(select * from table_1,table_2)
```

Comment: @MahmoudGamal: I am writing this query in c# windows application and connecting SQL server express edition 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server you can use:

```
SELECT * 
INTO table_3
FROM table_1, table_2
```

If you want to join the two tables based on some key then:

```
SELECT * 
INTO table_3
FROM table_1 JOIN table_2 on table_1.ID = table_2.FKID
```

You may see: [SQL SERVER – CTAS – Create Table As SELECT – What is CTAS?](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/04/30/sql-server-ctas-create-table-as-select-what-is-ctas/)

Comment: sir I wish to create table_3 along with select statements.

Comment: @user, the first statement in answer will create a table `table_3` after selecting records from `select * from table_1,table_2` which would be Cartesian product. IN SQL Server, that is the syntax to `create table as select`

Answer (score 0):

This can be used to create another table of same type

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
  AS (SELECT * FROM old_table);
```